# Fatal error: UnCSS: could not open

Tags: css, uncss, gulp-uncss

I'm trying to remove all of the unused css in the framework I'm using by using uncss. But when I try I get the error:

> file:///C:/Users/Angus/Desktop/FTTL%20website%20submit/index.html:15 in onload
>   Fatal error: UnCSS: could not open C:\Users\Angus\Desktop\FTTL website%20submit\css\main.css

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Have you tried it without whitespace in the folder/file names?

Comment: Man i should have known it was something that simple, thanks for the help mate

Answer (score 0):

Iyou forget to handle the first space properly (`FTTL website%20submit`) in the path, if you change the folder name or escape it properly (like `FTTL%20website%20submit`) it might work.

Edit: Or the other way around and the `%20` substitution for the path was not working for the second space. (I am not familiar with uncss.)

(In my opinion it is best not using spaces in file and folder names.)